# Return command within Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, return

## QUESTION

I have just started with python. I am trying to loop back this basic program i'm working on to the beginning.

Current process just breaks ends program and i'm not sure what i'm missing. How can I reorient return/select again to make this work out?

## PROGRAM INFO

- ultimate formula to reach is something like (diameter * quantity = x1) ~ x1 is true or false for correct conduit sizing table.
- diameter will depend on cabling type - multiple states to be added later for mix and match of types/quantities and addition of cable types for convenience.

## PROGRAM START

```
import random
import sys
import os

def prog01():
    print("")
od = float(input("Please input the outer dimension of your wire size in decimal form: "))
quantity = float(input("Please choose how many cables you have: "))

# diameter of cabling
def outer(od):
    try:
        od = float(od)
        print (od * quantity)
    except ValueError:
        print ('A numeric value was not input in the program. Please only use numeric information')

# quantity of cabling
def number(quantity):
    try:
        quantity = float(quantity)
    except ValueError:
        print ('A numeric value was not input in the program. Please only use numeric information')

# reference
outer(od)
number(quantity)


def select_again():

        while True:
            again = input("Do you have more cable types to add to your system? Please type y for yes or n for no: ")
            if again not in {"y","n"}:
                print("please enter valid input")
            elif again == "n":
                break
            elif again == "y":
                return prog01()


# sizing tables - true/false statements
x1 = (od * quantity)

# emt_list = over 2 wires @ 40% ['.122', '.213', '.346', '.598', '.814', '1.342', '2.343', '3.538', '4.618', '5.901']
emt_list = ['1/2" Conduit','3/4" Conduit','1" Conduit','1&1/4" Conduit', '1&1/2" Conduit','2" Conduit','2&1/2" Conduit',
            '3" Conduit','3&1/2" Conduit','4" Conduit',]

if x1 <= .122:
    print (emt_list [0])
elif x1 <= .213:
    print (emt_list [1])
elif x1 <= .346:
    print (emt_list [2])
elif x1 <= .598:
    print (emt_list [3])
elif x1 <= .814:
    print (emt_list [4])
elif x1 <= 1.342:
    print (emt_list [5])
elif x1 <= 2.343:
    print (emt_list [6])
elif x1 <= 3.538:
    print (emt_list [7])
elif x1 <= 4.618:
    print (emt_list [8])
elif x1 <= 5.901:
    print (emt_list [9])
if x1 >= 5.902:
    print ('You will need more than one piece of conduit')

select_again()

# rmc_list to come = over 2 wires @ 40% []
```

Comment: No sure what your question is, could you please clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your current code is that when you enter your select again loop, it only leaves the input loop itself when you enter 'n'. When you enter 'y', the function prog01() runs, but all it does is print a new line and return None, so the program goes back into the select again loop.

To get it to do what you want, you should replace the function prog01() with a while True loop statement, and have your separate while True loop for the yes or no query break on either 'y' or 'n', and have the outer loop break if the input return was 'n'.

I've also added .strip().lower() to the end of your input query to account for accidental spaces and remove case sensitivity, and changed it to a raw_input() call, since I don't know if your using python 2.x or 3.x. If your using 3.0+, you can just leave it as an input() call.

```
import random
import sys
import os

def outer(od):
    try:
        od = float(od)
        print (od * quantity)
    except ValueError:
        print ('A numeric value was not input in the program. Please only use numeric information')
def number(quantity):
    try:
        quantity = float(quantity)
    except ValueError:
        print ('A numeric value was not input in the program. Please only use numeric information')

while True:
    od = float(input("Please input the outer dimension of your wire size in decimal form: "))
    quantity = float(input("Please choose how many cables you have: "))

    # diameter of cabling


    # quantity of cabling

    # reference
    outer(od)
    number(quantity)

    # sizing tables - true/false statements
    x1 = (od * quantity)

    # emt_list = over 2 wires @ 40% ['.122', '.213', '.346', '.598', '.814', '1.342', '2.343', '3.538', '4.618', '5.901']
    emt_list = ['1/2" Conduit','3/4" Conduit','1" Conduit','1&1/4" Conduit', '1&1/2" Conduit','2" Conduit','2&1/2" Conduit',
                '3" Conduit','3&1/2" Conduit','4" Conduit',]

    if x1 <= .122:
        print (emt_list [0])
    elif x1 <= .213:
        print (emt_list [1])
    elif x1 <= .346:
        print (emt_list [2])
    elif x1 <= .598:
        print (emt_list [3])
    elif x1 <= .814:
        print (emt_list [4])
    elif x1 <= 1.342:
        print (emt_list [5])
    elif x1 <= 2.343:
        print (emt_list [6])
    elif x1 <= 3.538:
        print (emt_list [7])
    elif x1 <= 4.618:
        print (emt_list [8])
    elif x1 <= 5.901:
        print (emt_list [9])
    if x1 >= 5.902:
        print ('You will need more than one piece of conduit')

    again = raw_input("Do you have more cable types to add to your system? Please type y for yes or n for no: ").lower().strip()
    while True:
        if again not in {"y","n"}:
            print("please enter valid input")
        else:
            break
    if again == "n":
        break


    # rmc_list to come = over 2 wires @ 40% []
```

Comment: Cheers, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Python 2`, You need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`